# Cleaning up KnockoutObservables

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using `KnockoutObservables` in my code that are not part of the viewModel, just because I like the ability to listen to their state.

However when I dispose the dispose the `HtmlElement` they are related to, I need to dispose them (I assume) to clear memory.

`ko.cleanNode` I assume clears subscriptions from nodes in the `data-bind`, which is not exactly what I have.

```
<div id="foo" data-bind="myCustomBinding: foo"></div>
```

Custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomBinding = {
    init: function (element: any, valueAccessor: () => any, allBindingsAccessor: () => any, viewModel: any, bindingContext: KnockoutBindingContext) {
        new FooClass($(element), valueAccessor());
    }
}
```

`MyFooClass` then is displaying as needed and creates many new `KnockoutObservables` as public properties. Other objects I create can use these. I assume `ko.cleanNode` does not handle this, so how can I clean them?

```
class FooClass {
    disposed: boolean = false;
    myInternalObservable: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable("test");

    constructor(public htmlElement: JQuery, public value: KnockoutObservable<any>) {
        // Processing
    }

    dispose(): void {
        if (this.disposed) {
            return;
        }
        // Do other disposing, unbind events, delete data
        // Dispose the ko?
        this.disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can use is `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, cleanUpFunction)`.  This allows you to execute code whenever Knockout removes your element (like in templating or control-flow bindings). Knockout will already be calling `ko.cleanNode` as part of `ko.removeNode` at that point, so it allows you to do any additional cleanup.  You could choose to call `dispose` on computed observables and destroy any widgets or other things that you have done in the custom binding.

Comment: I already know it is being disposed, but how do I dispose of the KO Observable inside my class? Is there a method on the KO object I call to dispose? Should I just `delete this.myInternalObservable`?

Comment: There is no specific API to dispose of an observable, so you could choose to delete it. Observables hold their subscriptions, so there is not a need to go out to other objects for clean up.  However, computed observables do have a `dispose` which will visit all of its subscriptions and dispose of them.